# What is the exact domain of a grammar?

Tags: terminology, comparative-linguistics, philosophy-of-language

E.g. transformational grammars or probabilistic grammars deal with language structures, branching, semantic ranging, etc. They are dealing with more or less 'rational', or logical cocepts.

But what if there are grammar which cover such aspects, as ethics (like any language with honorifics, or with status sociolects, like Tamil), or grammars of emotions (from Tamil concepts of agams to emotions coded in grammars of [Australian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aversive_case) and Amazonian languages)?

What are the exact domains of language grammars? Are they ontological, and if they are, is that explicitly or implicitly determined?

Comment: The use of honorifics is not typically understood by English speakers to be an ethical issue--it is rather an issue relating to verbal etiquette and more generally pragmatics.  I do not know what the term "grammar of emotions" could possibly mean.   I do not know what a "domain" of grammar is in the context of your question, let alone what it means for such a domain to be ontological in an implicitly or explicitly determined way.   Please explain your terms, preferably with examples.

Comment: One possible definition: 'grammar' attempts to model the knowledge inside the human brain which enables the production and comprehension of language. But the exact borders of what's included in 'language' are fuzzy.

Comment: And to add to what @JamesGrossmann said: I work with Australian languages and I don't know what you mean by '...emotions encoded in grammars of Australian and Amazonian languages'.

Comment: This question is asking for clarification about what the term "grammar" means, what the scope of the term is, so I'm adding the "terminology" tag.

Comment: Manjusri, as other users are pointing out, there are a few unclear terms in your question. This certainly makes the question very difficult (if not impossible) to answer. Would you mind to improve it and make it more constructive?